# Combine NSArrayController with NSTableview method "objectValueFor"

Tags: nstableview, nsarraycontroller

Can I use NSArrayController for my tableview , and using simultaneously this method : ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?
```

The idea behind:
I do not want to loose the benefits of the arraycontroller  ( insert, update, delete ...) but I would like to have control on additional columns to display. The information inside these columns are calculated and formatted; values are coming from the array that the arraycontroller manages (Core Data).

I am afraid this is not possible because controller and tableviewfunction excludes each other ...

Comment: It is possible to combine `NSArrayController` with calculated values. Is the table view cell-based or view-based?

Comment: Have you tried to use `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)`? What happened?

Comment: It is a view-based tableview. I am using Xcode 13.2.1 and Swift. The columns are bound in the "oldfashioned" way by objectValue.someProperty

Comment: Yes, I tried tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:) - but it is never called because the tableview is bound to the controller :-)

Comment: In my test project `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)` is called. Does the class adopt `NSTableViewDataSource`?

Comment: Alternative solution: set the value in `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` instead.

Comment: Another solution: Add the computed properties to the Core Data Entity class in an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Willeke,  I got it made finally by using a extension for my entity.

```
extension ImportLog {
 
    // Splits the imported lines into individual words

    // For each entity, I split the property "line" .
    // Later, in the objc computed property, I pick column number x

    var splittedText:[String.SubSequence]{
        return(self.line!.split(separator: ";"))
    }
    
    // col1
    @objc var f1: String {
        get {
            let theColumn = 0
            var text:String = ""
            if ( splittedText.count-1 >= theColumn) {
                text = String(splittedText[theColumn])
            }
            return text
        }
        set {
            // no need to set something
        }
    }
 }
```

The computed property "f1" of the entity can now be bound in the XIB file
by "Table Cell View.objectValue.f1"

[image]